# sanitize vimeo embed code?

Tags: esc-textarea, wp-kses

I have a custom meta box with a textarea where users can drop in vimeo embed code.

Should I sanitize this code before I update_post_meta, and, if so, how should I go about it? I don't want to strip out important information (like the iframe)...I just want to make sure nothing malicious is getting entered.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a custom validation/sanitization callback, and hook it into `publish_post` (and/or `draft_post` and/or `future_post`, as applicable). For example:

```
<?php
function wpse_44807_update_custom_post_meta() {
    // Globalize the $post object
    global $post;
    // If our custom post meta key is set, sanitize it;
    // otherwise, return false
    $my_post_custom = ( isset( $_POST['_my_post_custom'] ? wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['_my_post_custom'] ? false );
    // Now, delete or update our custom post meta key
    if ( false == $my_post_custom ) {
        delete_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_post_custom' );
    } else {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_post_custom', $my_post_custom );
    }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'wpse_44807_update_custom_post_meta' );
add_action( 'draft_post', 'wpse_44807_update_custom_post_meta' );
?>
```

Note that I'm sanitizing using the [`wp_filter_nohtml_kses()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_filter_nohtml_kses) filter, which would be appropriate if you are expecting, say, a video ID or something similarly alpha-numeric. Your choice of sanitization will change, depending on the type of expected input.

Also: I'm using an underscore-prefixed custom post meta key, which is appropriate if you're defining a custom post meta box for your custom post meta key. (The underscore prefix hides this meta key from the generic "custom field" meta box drop-down.)

Answer (score 0):

`update_post_meta()` will sanitize it for database insertion for you. What you really need to be watching for is malicious HTML and such that would affect the output. For that you will need a regex or some other means of comparison to a known/desired format. To handle that I would recommend only accepting the video ID or something of that nature where you can strictly control how the output is done, rather than allowing the user to supply you with the iframe and such.

Comment: Actually, [`update_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) doesn't do any validation or sanitization; it simply replaces one DB value with another.

Comment: are iframes considered malicious? Because I need that for the vimeo embed!

Comment: @ChipBennett I believe you're incorrect. `update_post_meta()` calls `update_metadata()`, which inserts the data with `$wpdb->update`, which does data sanitization as per [this page in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation). I could be wrong...and by all means correct me if I am, but it wouldn't make any sense to me to do all the `stripslashes()` and such that is done on the data if it was expecting sanitized data, as that would unsanitize it.

Comment: @m0r7if3r `$wpdb->update` doesn't *sanitize* (or *validate*) data; rather, it *escapes* data. Data escaping *may or may not* be sufficient, depending on the expected data.

Comment: @redconservatory iframes are not inherently malicious, but I could very easily send an `<iframe>` that DIDN'T contain a vimeo embed, and, barring some pretty brilliant filtering on your part, it would be displayed on your site. On the other hand, if YOU create the iframe from a video id, then you know it will be in one format with VERY little deviation. Even still, you'll need to filter the users' input for malicious stuff, but that should be as easy as checking length and ensuring that you're only receiving alphanumerics.

Comment: @ChipBennett I see where you're coming from...for me sanitization for database input is merely escaping the data. Sanitization of the data itself is a whole different matter, and I covered that in my post as well. IMO, that should be done before you get to the point of using `update_post_meta()`, which should be fed only sanitized (unescaped) data.